# Will parentheses make program slower?

Tags: ruby, performance, parentheses

I'm just wondering if using parentheses in Ruby makes a program slower. I know it's common to omit them, but for me, using parentheses increases readability.

Comment: "makes program slower" - No, that'd be silly.

Comment: Also follow [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for references. There are some conventions where parentheses are not used.

Comment: You should write code for humans, not for machines. If parentheses increase readability, use them.

Comment: What happened when you measured it?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time spent while running a ruby program is spent executing the code after parsing has been done. Whether you include parentheses or not affects the tokenization/parsing phase, which is a minor part of the total execution time. Even if there were any difference, it should be negligible.

Answer (score -3):

There is no difference if your are using parenthesis while calling method or not.

So these lines mean exactly the same:

```
puts "Hello!"

puts("Hello!")
```

There are some standard rules which you can follow

Use parentheses for all method calls that take arguments, except for the methods puts and p (and later: require and include).

If a method does not take any arguments, then do not add empty parentheses, omit them.

Comment: The OP knows that your two expressions are equivalent. The OP is not asking about that.